# Web API 2 call from Proxy Server

Tags: https, asp.net-web-api2, reverse-proxy

I have java scripts web application calling my ASP.NET web API 2 Service under same web site in my AppServer. The application is working fine.

I setup Proxy Server and URL Rewrite to my Application Server. Everything is working fine with **Http** but can't call web api from JavaScript with **Https**

I put CROS and add the Proxy Server but still doesn't work.

But I can directly call web api with **https**

Kindly Advice!

Regards,
Si Thu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that it is because of Mixed Content Issue between proxy server and application server. App Server also need to be HTTPS

Issue is solved by adding certificate in App Server.